# Find file name using wildcard in C

Tags: c, linux, wildcard

I need to find the name of a file using * in a C program.  There is exactly 1 file in the specific folder that has the extension .UBX.  I can do this in terminal but it doesn't work in C.  Can anyone give me example code to do this?

```
//There is exactly 1 file that ends in .UBX
#define FILE_TO_SEND    "/home/root/logs/*.UBX"

fd = open(FILE_TO_SEND, O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html

Comment: can you give some example?  the example on that page is sparse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FILE_TO_SEND "/home/root/logs/*.UBX"

int
main (void)
{
    glob_t globbuf;

    glob(FILE_TO_SEND, 0, NULL, &globbuf);

    if (globbuf.gl_pathc > 0)
    {
        int fd = open(globbuf.gl_pathv[0], O_RDONLY);

        // ...
    }

    globfree(&globbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it what the OP asked for?